# status change on website based on twitter post time

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

So what I want is when I post on Twitter, my status on my website changes to online. (default is offline) I want it to stay online for 15 minutes after the post, before turning back to offline. I want it so it changes to online every time I post, resetting the 15 min timer.

Comment: Cool so what did you do to make this work?

Comment: Post your code here, then we can help you.

Comment: You have a clear plan, that's a good start.  How have you tried to do this so far?  Have you taken a look at the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api) to see if you can find something that'll help, for example?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.